# Jquery selector (this) not in function

Tags: jquery, this

I have a small code here that I cannot figure out if what is wrong, I think my code is okay but i suspect the `this` selector in jquery seems not in function after the `.post` request.

Here is my code:

```
$('.days').each(function() {
        day = jQuery.trim($(this).attr('id'));
        //this validates if there are events in this day
        $.post('includes/genAct.php', { thisDay: day, action: 'getMyEvent' }, function(data) {
            if(data != 0) {
                $(this).css('background', '#000').css('color', 'red');
            } 
        });
    });
```

If I make an alert of the returned `data` it seems gone working correctly. Is there any follow up ideas there. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is not a fixed variable, it changes depending on the context.

Inside the `post` success handler, it may not mean the same thing as outside it.

I would suggest caching the result:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

From that point on you can use `$this` to refer to the current element, no matter where you are within the `each` function.

Comment: Thank you for your query, I already resolved the problem but I omitted the `$` in variable declaration, and named to `myThis` instead of `$this`, But thanks anyway..:)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `each` function like this:

```
$('.days').each(function(i, val) {
 //the variable val returns the current element
});
```

You can use `val` instead of `this`.

`i` is the current index by the way.. :]

Comment: aha.. that is also a pretty cool idea, I am thingking I will try that later in using `.each` function. Thank you